# Python ftplib Corrupting Files?

Tags: python, ftp, corruption

I'm downloading files in Python using ftplib and up until recently everything seemed to be working fine. I am downloading files as such:

```
ftpSession = ftplib.FTP(host,username,password)
ftpSession.cwd('rlmfiles')
ftpFileList = filter(lambda x: 'PEDI' in x, ftpSession.nlst())
ftpFileList.sort() 
for f in ftpFileList:
    tempFile = open(os.path.join(localDirectory,f),'wb')
    ftpSession.retrbinary('RETR '+f,tempFile.write)
    tempFile.close()
ftpSession.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Up until recently it was downloading the files I needed just fine, as expected. Now, however, My files I'm downloading are corrupted and just contain long strings of garbage ASCII. I know that it is not the files posted onto the FTP I'm pulling them from because I also have a Perl script that does this successfully from the same FTP.

If it is any additional info, here's what the debugger puts out in the command prompt when downloading a file:

[image]

Has anyone encountered any issues with corrupted file contents using `retrbinary()` in Python's ftplib?

I'm really stuck/frustrated and haven't come across anything related to possible corruption here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue yesterday when I was attempting to download text files. Not sure if that is what you were doing, but since you say it has ASCII garbage in it, I assume you opened it in a text editor because it was supposed to be text.

If this is the case, the problem is that the file is a text file and you are trying to download it in binary mode.

What you want to do instead is retrieve the file in ASCII transfer mode.

```
tempFile = open(os.path.join(localDirectory,f),'w')  # Changed 'wb' to 'w'
ftpSession.retrlines('RETR '+f,tempFile.write)       # Changed retrbinary to retrlines
```

Unfortunately, this strips all the new-line characters out of the file. Yuck!

So then you need to add the stripped out new-line characters again:

```
tempFile = open(os.path.join(localDirectory,f),'w')
textLines = []
ftpSession.retrlines('RETR '+f,textLines.append)
tempFile.write('\n'.join(textLines))
```

This should work, but it doesn't look as nice as it could. So a little cleanup effort would get us:

```
temporaryFile   = open(os.path.join(localDirectory, currentFile), 'w')
textLines       = []
retrieveCommand = 'RETR '

ftpSession.retrlines(retrieveCommand + currentFile, textLines.append)
temporaryFile.write('\n'.join(textLines))
```